# How to search for open questions with large open bounties?

Tags: support, search, bounties, data-explorer

I'm trying to construct a query to find open questions with open bounties above a particular size.

Questions that either currently have or previously had bounties can be found on [data.stackexchange.com](http://data.stackexchange.com) by looking for associated `Votes` records with a `VoteTypeId` of `8` (`= BountyStart`).

The problem is when trying to restrict these to ensure the bounty hasn't already been awarded or closed.

Can think of two possible ways:

1. Look for questions with no associated `Vote` record with a `VoteTypeId` of `9` (`= BountyClose`).
2. Bounties last for a week so restrict the `BountyOpen` records to those with a `CreationDate` under a week ago: `WHERE DATEADD(d, 7, vob.CreationDate) >= GETDATE()`

But neither appears to be eliminating all questions where the bounty has ended. E.g. at the time of writing, only 2 of the 5 questions returned by [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/133043) (which includes *both* criteria) have an open bounty.

Am I missing something? Is there another way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Data Explorer is not updated constantly. It's updated once a week on Sunday morning. A bounty lasts for 7 days, so a bounty started on a Monday after the data update wouldn't ever get shown by your query, because it would be expired by the time the data got updated again.

A better way to get this information would be using the Stack Exchange API. There's an API call for [`/questions/featured`](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/featured-questions) that returns a list in [JSON format of all bountied questions](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/featured-questions#order=desc&sort=activity&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true). You could then parse that to sort the list by bounty size and display it.

Comment: Good answer but I'd like to do this all online if possible, ideally a one-click URL but if not, a bit of online copying and pasting would surfice. So am now wondering if there is any way of parsing/sorting the JSON results online...

Comment: @SteveChambers you could probably set up a jsFiddle. You can call the API and parse JSON from JavaScript. Although if you have your own site you could just set up the script there.