# Can we have a search option for questions with bounties? (No, I don't mean hasnotice:1)

Tags: feature-request, search, bounties

Over the years, there have been multiple requests asking how to search for questions and answers with bounties.

- *[How can I search for bounty questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54476/351462)* (Jun 21 '10)
- *[How can I find questions that I have asked that currently have bounties on them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62321/351462)* (Aug 26 '10)
- *[Advanced search criteria for bounty questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68253/351462)* (Oct 21 '10)
- *[Advanced search option to include questions with bounty among the search criteria and other cool search options](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71079/351462)* (Nov 28 '10)
- *[Query bounties set by specific user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78294/351462)* (Feb 7 '11)
- *[How to show Unanswered question filtered by bounty request?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83514/351462)* (Mar 17 '11)
- *[Is there a way to search for expired bounties?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105780/351462)* (Sep 11 '11)
- *[List previously featured questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108696/351462)* (Oct 7 '11)
- *[Is there a way to search for past bounties and their amounts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122917/351462)* (Feb 20 '12)
- *[Search for answers that have been awarded bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127683/351462)* (Mar 31 '12)
- *[Can we get some better bounty hunting tools?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130252/351462)* (Apr 24 '12)
- *[How to search only unanswered questions with an open bounty ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144952/351462)* (Aug 26 '12)
- *[Is there a way to search questions with bounties (ever having had a bounty)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157195/351462)* (Nov 30 '12)
- *[Is there a special option to search featured only?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158392/351462)* (Dec 11 '12)
- *[Finding featured questions without answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165158/351462)* (Jan 26 '13)
- *[Why :hasbounty search option was never implemented?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169239/351462)* (Feb 27 '13)
- *[Searching for open questions with large open bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194698/351462)* (Aug 26 '13)
- *[Finding Featured Unanswered Posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198397/351462)* (Sep 26 '13)
- *[Syntax to search for bounty questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220340/351462)* (Feb 10 '14)
- *[add an hasBounty:bool in search tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223191/351462)* (Feb 26 '14)
- *[Find bounty questions for specific tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239269/351462)* (Sep 12 '14)
- *[Show only questions with a bounty and without an accepted answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250288/351462)* (Feb 26 '15)
- *[How to find past questions within a particular tag that offered a bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261795/351462)* (Jul 31 '15)
- *[How to search for all questions with bounties across the network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269017/351462)* (Nov 6 '15)
- *[How can I find a list of questions that used to have a bounty, i.e. the bounty has been awarded?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269404/351462)* (Nov 15 '15)
- *[How to see featured (bounty) questions from all Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278695/351462)* (Apr 21 '16)

Currently, there isn't a search option to search questions with bounties. ([The closest alternative is `hasnotice:1`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/54477/351462), but it includes posts with [any type of notice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125457/351462).)

**Can a search option `hasbounty:` be added to find questions with bounties?**

Comment: This is clear duplicate. The original request is not rejected. Nothing changed since then. No point re-posting this and leaving it open.